# How to modified field from URL using python3

Tags: python-3.x

Hi all I need to modified URL using pthon3 script. For example here is a my script output  " [http://10.10.10.5/dvwa/vulnerabilities/fi/?page=include.php"](http://10.10.10.5/dvwa/vulnerabilities/fi/?page=include.php%22) and I would like to remove "include.php" from my output. So I want to output is "http://10.10.10.5/dvwa/vulnerabilities/fi/?page=" how can I do for it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlparse, urljoin

url  = "http://10.10.10.5/dvwa/index.php"

cookies = {'security' : 'low', 'PHPSESSID':'ev5mlspqdiklrgaqfqbh00act0'}

r = requests.post(url, cookies = cookies)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for link in soup.findAll('a', href = True):

    href_csrf = (link['href'])

    if "fi" in href_csrf:

        csrf_url = urljoin(url, href_csrf)

        print("Found fi : ", csrf_url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = "http://10.10.10.5/dvwa/vulnerabilities/fi/?page=include.php"

url = url.replace("include.php", "")

print(url)
```

You could do something like that.
Where you replace the part you dont want with nothing.